# Change Textfield from another class?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I start out with my sourcecode:

**FORM**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace software
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        try
        {
            MyClassTwo two = new MyClassTwo();
two.putValue();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.show("Error!");
        }
    }
}
```

**MyClassTwo**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace software
{
    public class MyClassTwo
    {
        Form1 myForm = new Form1();

        public void putValue()
        {
            myForm.textbox1.Text = "Hello";
        }
    }
}
```

I want to change the content of the **textbox** in **MyClassOne**. When i do it like this it doesnt work, just nothing happens. Can anyone help me with that? I updated the code.

Comment: that's not even close to compile-able.  You have no methods.

Comment: This code looks strange. You can't write statements on class level. You've to put all statements into methods or property getters and setters. Please fix these problems. Class two sets the Text of the textbox. This works correct. I think the problem could be that you create a new instance every time but shown is any other instance.

Comment: That is just rudimantery to show what i mean, the software itself runs well in c#

Comment: @user3877230 nevertheless should the code be correct because it's much easier to understand. Nobody knows when you call the code of class two or which instances are used. I'm still of the opinion that you always create a new instance of class one and display any other instance.

Comment: first of all you need to know how to write a method!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form that your MyClassTwo is referring to is not the same form as the one you are trying to set the text in. Your MyClassTwo is creating an entirely new instance of the Form and setting the text of that, which you never see.

without trying toooo hard, could you try something like this?

```
public class MyClassTwo
{

    public void putValue(Form1 myForm)
    {
        myForm.textbox1.Text = "Hello";
    }
}
```

and

```
 try
    {
        MyClassTwo two = new MyClassTwo();
        two.putValue(this);
    }
```

The idea is simply to pass the form that you want to change the text in, opposed to creating a new form inside of MyClassTwo.

Comment: @user3877230 glad to hear it :)